# Tracking a hashtag on twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I am looking to write an application that can track a hashtag in twitter, get the id and text, and storing this in a MySQL database. So the application should be able to -

1. Keep checking to see if anyone has tweeted on a particular hashtag (eg - #example).
2. Store the details of the tweet.

I have code that can request twitter to search for a hashtag, and returns a list of 20 tweets with the given hashtag.

So now my questions are:

1. How do I make sure that the same tweet is not pulled up again? (I can always store the tweet ID and check to see if it already exists when adding a new tweet, but not sure if this is the right way to go about it)
2. I want to do this over a few hours, so will I need to include any kind of refresh code or something that can constantly keep running the search? (Specifically, I want to search for NEW tweets with the hashtag, not existing ones. So anyone who tweets the hashtag AFTER I start tracking, I want those tweets to get saved)

Any more information/code that is needed, please do ask and I can post it here! Bear with me, I am a beginner at this.

Answer (score -1):

So, I think you should use regular expressions -> [Here](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

Twitter has the following structure of tweets:

```
`<div class="tweet original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable js-original-tweet" data-you-block="false" data-you-follow="false" data-expanded-footer="<div class="js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer"> … tabindex="-1">Details</a> </span> </div> </div>" data-user-id="25324805" data-name="~*Beebe♡Bluff*~" data-screen-name="UrBabygurrl" data-item-id="440556385688748032" data-tweet-id="440556385688748032" data-feedback-key="stream_status_440556385688748032"`
```

Maybe should you filter tweets by data-item-id ?
If you want to check for tweets every hour, day, week, month etc. you should use cron :)

Comment: I am mainly trying to understand how the listening process works :) Do I need to put the get tweets function in some kind of loop statement? Or is it automatically going to get all the tweets by itself? How does it know that a given tweet is new, and wasn't already captured by it previously?

Comment: -1 [Don’t parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/216074). Also, Twitter offers an API, so there is *really* no need to query the Twitter website.

Comment: Thanks for advice :) I forgot about Twitter API, I'm so stupid :)